# TilePane inside Scroll Pane just occupies a small portion of the screen

Tags: javafx-2

I have a TilePane consisting of images, the images inside the tilepane depends on the numer of the images inside the folder selected by the user. But there was no scrollpane in the tilepane, so I decided to put the tilePane inside a ScrollPane, but I am not able to control the height of the scrollpane to occupy the whole page.

```
    public ScrollPane viewGallery(Stage stage)
    {
        ScrollPane root = null;
        final TilePane tile = new TilePane();
        try{

            root = new ScrollPane();
            tile.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
            tile.setVgap(4);
            tile.setHgap(4);
            tile.setPrefHeight(stage.getHeight());
            tile.setStyle("-fx-background-color: DAE6F3;");
            File[] listOfFiles = outputFolder.listFiles();
            System.out.println(outputFolder.listFiles().length);

            for (File file : listOfFiles) {

                System.out.println(file.getPath());
                Image image = new Image("file:"+file.getPath());
                ImageView iv2 = new ImageView();
                iv2.setImage(image);
                iv2.setFitWidth(250);
                iv2.setPreserveRatio(true);
                iv2.setSmooth(true);
                iv2.setCache(true);
                tile.getChildren().add(iv2);
            }

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        root.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);    // Horizontal scroll bar
        root.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);    // Vertical scroll bar
        root.setFitToHeight(true);
        root.setFitToWidth(true);
        root.setContent(tile);      
        return root;
    }
```

The output is something life this..[image]

Comment: tile.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);

Comment: hm. instead of `tile.setPrefHeight(stage.getHeight());`, try to bind it: `tile.prefHeightProperty().bind(stage.heightProperty());`. It could be that you set the prefHeight at a time where the stage isn't fully sized yet.

Comment: How are you adding the scroll pane to the scene? Are you wrapping it in another Parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with the scrollPane or the TilePane, I was adding the scrollPane to a borderPane and i was using :

```
border.setTop(viewGallery(Stage stage));
```

Just changing the above code to the below code resolved my issue..

```
border.setCenter(viewGallery(Stage stage));
```

The docs are pretty clear:

The top and bottom children will be resized to their preferred heights and extend the width of the borderpane. The left and right children will be resized to their preferred widths and extend the length between the top and bottom nodes. And the center node will be resized to fill the available space in the middle